# Running inside of a building or dungeon

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement

Are there any official rules for movement being hampered in an enclosed space. It seems to me that 3x/4x running should be quite difficult in halls where you would have to turn tight corners and such but nothing is really specified about this situation that I can find.

Comment: [This question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21375/can-i-use-run-in-an-area-where-there-is-no-straight-path-available/21382#21382) has some answers which are relevant, even though the actual question is almost the opposite.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A creature that moves its Speed isn't running. Running *is* different. The [Run](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Run) action reads

> You can run as a full-round action. If you do, you do not also get a 5-foot step. **When you run, you can move up to four times your speed in a straight line** (or three times your speed if you're in heavy armor). You lose any Dexterity bonus to AC unless you have the Run feat.
>
> You can run for a number of rounds equal to your Constitution score, but after that you must make a DC 10 Constitution check to continue running. You must check again each round in which you continue to run, and the DC of this check increases by 1 for each check you have made. When you fail this check, you must stop running. A character who has run to his limit must rest for 1 minute (10 rounds) before running again. During a rest period, a character can move no faster than a normal move action.
>
> You can't run across difficult terrain or if you can't see where you're going.
>
> A run represents a speed of about 13 miles per hour for an unencumbered human.

So, yeah, a creature can go *really* far in a full-round action of running in straight line, but the creature must *stop* before it can turn a corner.

Note, also, that for really tight spaces [squeezing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Terrain-and-Obstacles) is another thing *again*.

Comment: Thanks, this came up wrt to the panicked condition. So does the "top speed" part of that imply this isn't actually a full run? The DM seemed to want the player to move at 4x through the building. If they have to "stop" to turn a corner does the turn end there?

Comment: That's up to the DM. I'd argue that while *Speed* is a game term, *top speed* is a description--fleeing at top speed, then, would, in fact, be a run. But a running creature--barring exceptions, obviously--must *stop* running before it can navigate a corner; as the run action's a full-round action, there isn't much *else* the typical creature can do on its turn after the run action. Further, a *very* restrictive DM can rule a panicked creature runs even 5 ft. if that's the random direction the creature travels and that's all the distance available--that's *really* harsh, though.

Comment: I would probably take "top speed" in this context to mean they use the furthest option they can.  If a Run would end sooner than a double-move (because of a corner), they should take the double-move.  If they can Run further than a double-move (a long hallway, say), they should probably Run.